# Clear WebBrowser additional control content to in a userform reuse it

Tags: excel, vba, webbrowser-control

I have created a user form and added a webbrowser control. I am loading PDF into the webbrowser control on the user form. It works just fine, but when I initialize the user form again from another user form it contains the Old written Content. How to clean the content?

This is the code I used

```
Private Sub UploadImage_Click()


Dim xDialog As FileDialog
Dim xDocumen As String

Set xDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
xDialog.Title = "Select Document"
xDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
If xDialog.Show = 0 Then Exit Sub
xDocumen = xDialog.SelectedItems(1)

Me.ImagePath.Caption = xDocumen

usfAdd.WebBrowser.Navigate2 "about:blank"
usfAdd.WebBrowser.Document.write "<HTML><Body><embed src=""" & xDocumen & """ width=""100%"" height=""100%"" /></Body></HTML>"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `.Refresh`

```vb
If usfAdd.Document Is Nothing Then
     usfAdd.Navigate2 "about:blank"
End If
usfAdd.Document.write "<HTML><Body><embed src=""" & xDocumen & """ width=""100%"" height=""100%"" /></Body></HTML>"
usfAdd.Refresh
```

Comment: Thanks, it cleans the content but I can't overwrite with new content and must restart the program to reuse it again.

Comment: @mahmoud Does it not show the document after you click Upload_Image ?

Comment: yes, it keeps showing a blank white page.